# ActionBar doesn't have the same view for different devices

Tags: java, android

There is the folliwing problem: I've made some Android app and there are 3 menu items (1 dropdown and 2 simple items):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_sort_by_size"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="СSort">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/girls_action_all"
                android:title="All"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/girls_action_best"
                android:title="Best"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/girls_action_new_people"
                android:title="New users today"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/girls_action_50_plus"
                android:title="Top 50"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/girls_action_100_plus"
                android:title="Top 100"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/girls_action_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_home"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="My page"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/girls_action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:orderInCategory="102"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Search"/>

</menu>
```

But one item ("Search") doesn't appear on the Action Bar if I use some devices; it appears in the Menu (after click by "Menu" button). I don't like it. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/girls_action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:orderInCategory="102"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Search"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` to `android:showAsAction="always"` for the search menu item.

`android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` will do as it is told - it will display the menu in the action bar if there is enough room; if not, it will overflow to the menu. Currently, all your menu items have this flag set and will compete for the limited space.

`android:showAsAction="always"` will force the item to be displayed in the action bar. This may cause them to overlap with other UI items if there is not enough room.

Or set `android:showAsAction="never"` for some of the other items that you don't want in the action bar.